# Can a Green Lantern ring be summoned by its wielder?

Tags: dc, green-lantern

Much like how Thor's hammer goes to him no matter where he is, can GL call for their rings?

Answer (score 13):

#### A Green Lantern can recall their rings from short distances, no more than twenty or thirty feet, even if it has been taken from them by subterfuge or force. However, unlike Mjolnir, a ring will not cross great distances to return to a ring-wielder, nor can a ring create a wormhole or cross dimensional barriers on its own.

[image]

- Rings can, however, be programmed with instruction algorithms which could include a "program" to return to a location or perform a specific action under certain conditions.
- Kyle Rayner preprogrammed his ring to seek him out and find him, should it ever be separated from him. Such programming was unique to Kyle Rayner's ring but likely could be replicated by other Green Lanterns who were willing to put in the time.
- Rings ARE able to cross great distances and opening wormholes for one purpose: to find new ring-bearers in the event of the death of their primary user.

[image]

Comment: nice answer with new 52 screens?

Comment: Considering how sophisticated the rings are and the fact that they can act independently, it seems kind of silly that the weilder couldn't summon it. I mean, what if the weilder was in a predicament where he needed it?

Comment: Why would he need to take it off in the first place? The ring can be completely invisible, so he would never need to be separated from it? Given the nature of his work, if someone CAN take his ring and mean to do him harm, then he has few choices anyway. Can you create a circumstance where he intentionally would leave the ring behind and hope to have it find him later at a designated location? Perhaps you could, but it certainly would be a strange circumstance, to be sure.

Comment: There was an issue earlier in Green Lantern Volume 4 where Hal and Cowgirl get kidnapped and taken to Russia and he left his ring in his appartment. Whenever he flies, he leaves the ring off. I, personally, just find it a tad bit bizzare that the most advanced technology in the universe, which has an AI that can act independenlty and travel vast distances, does not have the capability to go to it's weilder when summoned.

Comment: You mean Hal's insistence on flying the experimental planes without wearing the ring? He says it makes him less vigilant and less aware. Okay, there is a precedent for it. As the Guardians have been fond of saying, the ring isn't magic. It is a technology and this ability you are speaking of isn't within its ability. It could be despite the sophisticated near AI capacity, the Guardians are leery of such independence due to their incredible mishap with their previous creations, the Manhunters. Given the massacre, I can understand their reluctance.